# How do I clean up dirty memory from CG Image

Tags: ios, memory-management, ios6, memory-leaks, cgimage

In my app, it seems like `CG image` is eating up a lot of dirty memory:

[image]

Is there any API to call to flush all the dirty image in the memory? In the code I am just resizing the images with [this library](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/), and I am putting only about 20 MB worth of pictures (no more than 1MB each) on the screen.

It works okay on regular iPad but it crashes on iPad mini. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Edit: Static analyser said the project is fine. Low memory [crash log is here](http://pastebin.com/2BVL5czy).

Comment: Run the static analyzer and see if you're not CGRelease()'ing away those images properly.

Comment: Also include the crash logs in case there may be any other reason as well.

Comment: Just updated the question with those info. Can you tell from the low memory crash log what went wrong?